# Can I use flexible conduit on a basement pole?

Tags: conduit, pole

I am working on installing a 220 outlet on a metal pole in my basement.  I’ve run the 4-wire yellow Romex over to the top of the pole (used a running-board attached under the joists).  Can I use non-metallic, liquid-tight conduit to go straight-down to the outlet box?  I’d much rather not have to mess with bending rigid conduit if I can avoid it (offset connectors aren’t long enough to go from the pole surface to the outside of the I-beam that the pole supports).  Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by changing wiring methods? Damage protection?

Comment: liquid-tight conduit is a overkill in your set up, but they are permitted

Comment: If this is a typical 4-inch round steel pole, you could use plastic or metal cable raceway.  Throw away the back part and tie the front part to the pole with hose clamps after installation of the outlet.   Or you could make one by cutting a piece of PVC pipe in half lengthwise.  Use an NM clamp in the outlet box, ie, the raceway doesn't have to interface properly with the box.  It's not a conduit, just a cover for the cable.

Answer (score -1):

The basic issue here is *protection from physical damage*. Otherwise there is no reason to bother with conduit indoors for *cable*. This answer is also based on the assumption that you still have sufficient cable and did not cut it short at the top of the pole. If you cut it short at the top of the pole then you need to join the cable to individual wires inside a junction box and run the wires through conduit down the pole. That is more work overall, though you get to use *much* smaller conduit (1/2" PVC 80 or RMC will work just fine).

Running NM cable through conduit is not easy in general. In fact, based on everything I have read, liquid-tight is the hardest type of conduit to run wires or cable through, so this would be a double problem.

But in any case, as far as I can tell non-metallic liquid-tight isn't even an option when physical protection is needed. The rules are a bit confusing to me. Everyone agrees on rigid metal conduit and PVC schedule 80. Beyond that it seems to vary a bit, but certain types ([non-metallic liquid-tight](https://up.codes/viewer/texas/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#356.12), [ENT](https://up.codes/viewer/texas/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#362.12)) are not allowed, many others are "sometimes". But the other thing is that you only have to provide protection up to some particular height. Unfortunately, that height seems to be somewhat opinion-based. Arguably somewhere in the 7 foot to 8 foot range seems to be acceptable.

So my recommendation is to use RMC (preferred, metal is good!) or PVC schedule 80 from just below the I-beam and down to the box, assuming the I-beam is at least 7 feet above the floor. No need to bend conduit - just get a piece of RMC cut to length, an offset nipple and a metal box and you're basically done. The only other thing you have to do is figure out how to securely attach it to the metal pole, but that is an issue no matter what type of conduit you use.

Since you reference yellow Romex, presumably that is 12 AWG. I also suspect the 4-wire you are referring to is really 3 insulated wires + ground, a.k.a. 12/3. According to the manufacturer's specs, that is 0.524" x 0.190". So the conduit has to be sized based on .524". Which means either RMC 3/4" (or larger) or PVC 80 1" (or larger).

You are also not limited to conduit. Some other options, depending on the type of pole, the planned use of the room (workshop vs. finished living space) and budget include:

- Box around the entire pole with wood.
- Box around the cable with sheet metal.
- Run the cable through other types of pipe. The pipe has to be strong enough to resist reasonable physical damage (PVC 40 vs. 80 being a rough guide to that, though I suspect there is some engineering specification somewhere...) but doesn't have to be "electrical conduit". A big old galvanized plumbing pipe pulled out from somewhere would work fine if it is decent shape, even though it would not be allowed as conduit for individual wires.

Comment: Do you have a code cite for your “liquid tight doesn’t provide physical protection” claim?

Comment: @nobody NEC 356.12, Not permitted where subject to physical damage.

Comment: I would think EMT would be acceptable also, 358.12 specifies not permitted *where subject to severe physical damage*. I doubt an inspector would judge a residential basement would rise to that level.